# Calculating datatable input text value and showing result in a outputtextbox

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am new to primefaces. I have a problem and the issue is , i have a inputtextbox inside a datatable and if i enter any value inside a textbox the count should display in a outputTextbox called total. I am not finding any solution. my code is

```
<p:dataTable id="venueNames" 
             var="test" 
             value="#{issueAdmitCardBean.venueNames}" 
             paginator="false" 
             rows="10" 
             styleClass="dataTable"                    
             rowIndexVar="index">

    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{test.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Name Of Venue">
        <h:outputText value="#{test.name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Maximum Capacity">
        <h:outputText value="#{test.capacity}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Allot No. of Candidates" >
        <h:inputText value="#{issueAdmitCardBean.venueNames[index].allotCandaidate}" 
                     style="width:50px;" 
                     onkeyup="doWork(#{test.capacity}, this.value);" 
                     required="true"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Exam Date">
        <p:calendar value="issueAdmitCardBean.examDate" 
                    pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" 
                    navigator="true" 
                    style="width:10px;"/>
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

I want to display the total right after the datatable . please give any suggestion and help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: please help to solve it

Comment: Total of what ? You probably need a method that listens to cell edit, and do the total in the backing bean and finally re-update the view with the new total.

Comment: I need the total of issueAdmitCardBean.venueNames[index].allotCandaidate . how can i get my total if user change the count of the allotatedCandidate

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you want to display the sum of the values of all `<h:inputText>`-Fields.
At the moment, there is no JSF-action in your code (no form, no submit, no ajax).
You may do it with Javascript and jQuery, or you try this:

```
<h:form>
  <p:dataTable>
    ...
    <p:column headerText="Allot No. of Candidates" >
      <h:inputText value="#{issueAdmitCardBean.venueNames[index].allotCandaidate}"
                   ... >
        <p:ajax event="change" update="@this total" />
      </h:inputText>

    </p:column>
  <p:dataTable>

  <h:outputText id="total" value="#{issueAdmitCardBean.total}"
</h:form>
```

And in the IssueAdmitCardBean:

```
public int getTotal(){
  int result = 0;
  for(VenueName venueName : this.venueNames){
    result += Integer.parseInt(venueName.getAllotCandaidate());
  }
  return result;
}
```

Please note, that this example is without exception handling and that I could not test it right now.

Comment: <p:ajax event="change" update="@this total" /> the it is not fount.and it has been showing error

Comment: Do you have a JSF/Primefaces-component with the id "total" in your code?

Comment: yes i have. but pages it not refreshing in onchange. when ever i refresh my page the only my method has been showing.

Comment: do you have the ajax-tag and the outputText in the same `h:form`?